# Amazon EC2 - Installed atop / htop but they don't show disk I/O stats

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I configured an AWS EC2 with Amazon AMI Linux and installed via yum atop and htop and they work correctly but they don't show any stats for the disk I/O as usual.

I tried some startup options with no luck and also running them with 'sudo'...

Is there any way to make them show it?

Edit: htop 1.0.1 and atop 1.27-3, same versions I have on another "real" server and these work out of the box...

By "usual" I mean the % of the I/O of the disk in use, something like this from atop:

```
DSK |          sda  | busy      1%  | read       6  |               | write    268  | KiB/r      4  | KiB/w      7  | MBr/s   0.00  |               | MBw/s   0.19  | avq    19.30  | avio 0.34 ms  |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try iotop.  If you are monitoring an EBS volume you can also see metrics, although not as real time, on the volume in the EC2 dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

To see disk I/O in `htop` you have to do the following:

1.Start htop:

```
$ htop
```

2.Press **F2** (setup).

3.Select `Columns`.

4.Navigate to `Available Columns` and select `WBYTES` and `RBYTES` by pressing **ENTER** on them.

5.Exit with **escape**.

You'll now have two columns with disk I/0 information.

[image]